# Cannot find the symbol method activateToolbar()

Tags: java, android

Why can't I use the activateToolbar() method?

I have a class called BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar mToolbar;
protected Toolbar activateToolbar() {
    if(mToolbar == null) {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar)
                findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        if(mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }
    }
    return mToolbar;
}
}
```

In MainActivity's onCreate method, I try to call the activateToobar() method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
private List<Photo> mPhotosList = new ArrayList<Photo>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private FlickrRecyclerViewAdapter flickrRecyclerViewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activateToolbar();
```

The Android Studio IDE 1.5.1 that I am using shows the activateToolbar() method in red letters; it says 'cannot resolve method activateToobar()' when I hover over it.  When I try to make the project, I get an error saying "cannot find symbol method activateToolbar()."

Comment: Does `MainActivity` extend `BaseActivity`? `public class MainActivity extends BaseActvity`

Comment: It sounds like you define `activateToolbar` in `BaseActivity`, and use it in (the unrelated class) `MainActivity`. Is that correct?

Comment: @George MainActivity MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

resueman Yes, activateToolbar() is defined in BaseActivity, and I am trying to use it in MainActivity

Comment: `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` is wrong. Look at my previous comment.

Comment: @ George Mulligan I changed MainActivity to extend BaseActivity and it works.  Will MainActivity extend AppCompatActivity too because BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your definition of `MainActivity`, it needs to extend `BaseActivity` where `activateToolbar()` is defined.

Right now your  `MainActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` and `BaseActivity` is unused

Comment: I changed MainActivity to extend BaseActivity and it works. Will MainActivity extend AppCompatActivity too because BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity? In other words, will this change limit MainActivity's function in any way?

Comment: Yes you can create a chain of classes that create a class hierarchy, and each inherits behavior from the parent. So MainActivity is both a BaseActivity and an AppCompatActivity